# Relation Between Power, Distance, Time and Mass

Tags: mass, electric-current, time, voltage, length

I was calculating something and reached this equation

$${Meter^2 \over Second^3} = {Volt * Ampere \over Kg}$$

Is it correct? Cause if it is... It will tell me I am on the right path.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! What are your thoughts? Please note that you are expected to have thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question. And it's important to detail where you're stuck and why, in order to attract good answers. You can consider checking the [advice on writing good questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By checking it yourself, by hand, you will

- review units definitions,
- practice some basic equations of physics,
- practice algebra,
- gain a better feeling for units,
- and in general learn more.

But if all you want is to check your equation, you can give [insect](https://insect.sh/) a try:

[image]